# add buy now button in homepage widget products list magento 2

Tags: magento2, widget, buy-now

How can i add `buynow button` on Homepage widget list products ?

hello, I amm using this module [magento2-buynow](https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-buynow)

but this add in category page and product page.

I need to add buy now button to homepage widget product list.

`This my widget code`

```
<?php
$type = 'widget-product-carousel';

$mode = 'grid';

$image = 'new_products_content_widget_grid';
$items = $block->getProductCollection()->getItems();

$showWishlist = true;
$showCompare = true;
$showCart = true;
$templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::DEFAULT_VIEW;
$description = false;
$data = $this->helper('Megnor\Framework\Helper\Data');
?>
<div class="block widget block-products-list <?= /* @noEscape */ $mode ?>">
    <?php if ($block->getTitle()): ?>
        <!-- <div class="block-title">
        <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($block->getTitle())) ?></strong>
    </div> -->
    <?php endif ?>
    <div class="block-new-content">
        <?= /* @noEscape */ '<!-- ' . $image . '-->' ?>
        <div class="products-<?= /* @noEscape */ $mode ?> <?= /* @noEscape */ $mode ?> wrapper products">
            <ol class="product-items <?= /* @noEscape */ $type ?>">
                <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
                <?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>
                <?php if ($iterator++ != 1): ?></li><?php endif ?>
                <li class="product-item">
                    <div class="product-item-info">
                        <div class="product-block-inner">
                            <div class="product-item-image">
                                <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>" class="product-item-photo">
                                    <?= $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml() ?>
                                </a>
                                <?php
                                $is_new = $data->checkProductIsNew($_item);
                                if($is_new) { ?>
                                    <span class="new-label"><?php echo __("New");?></span>
                                <?php } ?>

                                <?php

                                $specialprice = $_item->getSpecialPrice();
                                $specialPriceFromDate = $_item->getSpecialFromDate();
                                $specialPriceToDate = $_item->getSpecialToDate();
                                $today =  time();
                                if ($specialprice) {
                                    if($today >= strtotime($specialPriceFromDate) && $today <= strtotime($specialPriceToDate) || $today >= strtotime($specialPriceFromDate) && is_null($specialPriceToDate)) {
                                        $originalPrice = $_item->getPrice();
                                        $finalPrice = $_item->getFinalPrice();
                                        $percentage = $percentage = round(($originalPrice - $finalPrice) * 100 / $originalPrice);
                                        ?>
                                        <span class="sale-label"><?php echo "-".$percentage."%";?></span>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                }
                                ?>
                                <?php if ($showWishlist): ?>
                                    <div class="actions-secondary" data-role="add-to-links">
                                        <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->isAllow() && $showWishlist): ?>
                                            <a href="#"
                                               data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAddToWishlistParams($_item) ?>' class="action towishlist" data-action="add-to-wishlist" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Wish List')) ?>">
                                                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')) ?></span>
                                            </a>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                            </div>
                            <div class="product-item-details">
                                <?php
                                echo $block->getProductPriceHtml($_item, $type);
                                ?>

                                <strong class="product-item-name">
                                    <a title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>"
                                       href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>"
                                       class="product-item-link">
                                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>
                                    </a>
                                </strong>

                                <?php if ($templateType): ?>
                                    <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, $templateType,true) ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if ($showWishlist || $showCompare || $showCart): ?>
                                    <div class="product-item-inner">
                                        <?php if ($showCart): ?>
                                            <div class="actions-primary">
                                                <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                                                    <?php if ($_item->getTypeInstance()->hasRequiredOptions($_item)): ?>
                                                        <button class="action tocart primary" data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl":{"url":"<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item)) ?>"}}' type="button" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>">
                                                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                                        </button>
                                                    <?php else: ?>
                                                        <?php
                                                        $postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
                                                        $postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item), ['product' => $_item->getEntityId()])
                                                        ?>
                                                        <button class="action tocart primary" data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */ $postData ?>' type="button" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>">
                                                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                                        </button>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                <?php else: ?>
                                                    <?php if ($_item->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                                        <div class="stock available"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span></div>
                                                    <?php else: ?>
                                                        <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span></div>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php if ($showCompare): ?>
                                            <div class="actions-secondary" data-role="add-to-links">
                                                <?php if ($block->getAddToCompareUrl() && $showCompare): ?>
                                                    <?php $compareHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare');?>
                                                    <a href="#" class="action tocompare" data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */ $compareHelper->getPostDataParams($_item) ?>' title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Compare')) ?>">
                                                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')) ?></span>
                                                    </a>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?= ($iterator == count($items)+1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add buynow button in custom widget after add to cart

**Final Code:**

```
<div class="actions-primary">
    <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
        <?php if ($_item->getTypeInstance()->hasRequiredOptions($_item)): ?>
            ...
            // Add to cart code
            ...
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php 
        // Get buynow block html
        $buyNowHtml = $this->getLayout()
                 ->createBlock('Prince\Buynow\Block\Product\ListProduct')
                 ->setProduct($_item)
                 ->setTemplate('Prince_Buynow::buynow-list.phtml')
                 ->toHtml();
        echo $buyNowHtml;
        ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        ...
        //In stock out of stock code
        ...
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello,
Please can you explain more. I have the same case. Your code not working